# how to mention globalization in view level in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

I have a problem in mentioning globalization in web.config file. It effects my full calendar events load and i don't add it in web.config one of my module  which accepts date from datepicker will not work. Model will fail.

So how to mention culture in page level like below which we mention in Webforms

```
<%@ Page Culture="en-IN" Language="C#" %> -- Webforms
```

How to mention same in MVC View

Comment: I guess you can use Culture = "en-IN"; in the cshtml file within a c# code block

Answer (score 0):

In root file Web.config should have that snippet of code:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Buddy.. I know how to mention it in web.config. Please read the question properly. I want to  know how to mention in View level in MVC as we mention in Page level in ASP.Net webforms